# Как сделать оранжевую обводку сообщения в дискорд?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу добавить в бота функцию: при отправки сообщения в личные сообщения на оранжевом фоне, так же, как на картинке.

Comment: Не вижу на фото оранжевого. Конкретизируйте плиз.

Comment: Я добавил картинку

Comment: Оранжевый фон автоматически появляется у упомянутых в данном сообщении пользователей

Answer (score 1):

**Фон как у тегов нельзя сделать у обычных сообщений**

Это делается с помощью Embed-объектов
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object

```py
async def test(ctx, *, user_id: int):
    user = await Client.fetch_user(user_id=user_id)
    await user.send('test')
```

Comment: Я понимаю что с помощью embed но что указывать кроме title, description, color?

Comment: Я добавил картинку, мне интересно как это сделать

Comment: вообще, вы скинули картинку, на которой просто тег, который сам на синем фоне изначально.

Comment: Я только одну оставил